# Can i update a field in a SQL set command, then use the new value in the same command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to set a value, then in the same SQL update stored proc refer to that new value, will this work?

When i try it seems the second update doesn't get updated until the second run of the stored proc (As if the first line getting updated doesn't not make the new value visible to the second field)

If this wont work would the best bet be to use a variable?

**I have the following command (Simplified):**

```
    UPDATE [dbo].[AU Sales Inv Line] SET
    [_On Rent Date] = "REALLY COMPLICATED CALCULATION",
    [_New Revenue] = (CASE WHEN [_On Rent Date] = XXX THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The syntax looks like SQL Server so I added the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method to do what you want is an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             <really complicated calculation> as newval
      from [AU Sales Inv Line] t
     )
update toupdate
    set [_On Rent Date] = newval,
        [_New Revenue] = (CASE WHEN newval = XXX THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END);
```

Comment: Great, Thanks that will do the job perfectly